# How do I force Visual Studio 2012 to run a project's pre-build events every time the project is built?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, pre-build-event

I have a pre-build event on a C# project -- when built from VS2010, this pre-build event runs on every build of the project. From VS2012, however, the pre-build event only runs when the project needs rebuilt, not on every build.

Is there a way to circumvent this behavior in VS2012 and forece the pre-build event to run on every build?